# How to link buttons in visual studio with c#?

Tags: c#, facebook, button

I just want it so that whenever I click on like button one, like button two should be clicked as well.

So how can I do it?

Actually I have a windows application form and have inserted a web browser in the form.  The form URL is some facebook page link.  So I want to like that page with my own created button (button 1).  Please guide me how can I do it using C#

This is an image which can explain my problem

[image]

Comment: When only using a `WebBrowser`, the only solution I'd come up with would be to parse the loaded HTML to detect a facebook "Like"-Button, then parse where the `href` attribute of that button, and have your `WebBrowser` go to that link when your Applications big "Like"-Button is clicked. There's not a convinient function the `WebBrowser` control that would let you detect all buttons / links in a loaded webpage, as far as I'm concerned. You have to simulate the button press. You could also just hardcode the link to the URL the Like-Button leads to and jump to that page un the button press.

Comment: Sorry Sir i could not understand you..

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Form with only a webbrowser in the background and a simple blue colored button.
[image]

In the `OnLoad()` function, we navigate to the facebook page. When the "Like" button is pressed, all HTML buttons are searched for the one whose `class`-attribute contains "PageLikeButton". When that like button is found, the `click()` function is executed upon it.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FacebookLiker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Go to that link
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/haadischool/?fref=ts");

        }

        private void btnLike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Scan the facebook page for a like button

            foreach(HtmlElement button in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                //Is this the like button?
                if (button.GetAttribute("className").Contains("PageLikeButton"))
                {
                    //yes, simulate the click!
                    button.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I visit the page without having liked it: 
[image]

And after I click the Form's "Like" button:

[image]

Ofcourse, this simple demo should be enhanced to handle the cases where there is no "Like"-button at all, you can do that by hooking the `DocumentCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser`, then searching for a "Like"-Button there. You can also detect wether the page was already liked. In that case, the `class` attribute you'll be searching for will be "PageLikedButton" (past-tense of "like").

Comment: Thank you so much sir,thank you so so so very much ,you solved my big problem.

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if this helped you.

Comment: Sir i want that if i am unliking  the page,it should be count so how can i make it...please help me sir